Question About the Proof of Every Polynomial With Complex Coefficients Has a Root in $\mathbb C$
I was reading Zorich's Mathematical Analysis and got stuck on the proof of Theorem 2 of Section 5.5.5.
$\textbf{Theorem 2}$ Every polynomial $P(z) = c_0+c_1z+\cdots+c_nz^n$ of degree $n\geq1$ with complex coefficients has a root in $\mathbb{C}$.
$\textbf{Proof}$ Without loss of generality, we may obviously assume that $c_n=1$. Let $\mu=\inf_{z\in{\mathbb{C}}}|P(z)|$. Since $P(z) = z^n(1+\frac{c_{n-1}}{z}+\cdots+\frac{c_0}{z^n})$, we have $|P(z)|\geq|z|^n(1-\frac{|c_{n-1}|}{|z|}-\cdots-\frac{|c_0|}{|z|^n})$, and obviously $|P(z)|>\max\{1,2\mu\}$ for $|z|>R$ if $R$ is sufficiently large. Consequently, the points of a sequence $\{z_k\}$ at which $0<|P(z_k)|-\mu<\frac{1}{k}$ lie inside the disk $|z|\leq R$.$\cdots\cdots$
I don't understand why $|P(z)|>\max\{1,2\mu\}$ for $|z|>R$ if $R$ is sufficiently large and why $0<|P(z_k)|-\mu<\frac{1}{k}$ lie inside the disk $|z|\leq R$. Thanks!

Actually, it should be $|P(z_k)|-\mu$ rather than $|P(z_k)-\mu|$.

This is some twisted logic by trying to give a compact argumentation. Assuming that no root exists, it is desired to show that (i) a positive minimum of $|P(z)|$ exists and that (ii) this minimum can be located in a bounded and thus compact subset. To get the positive minimum a restriction to a compact set would be nice, but to construct the compact set the value of the minimum would be a useful ingredient.
One can extract the lemma: For any $c>0$ one can find a radius $R>0$ so that $|P(z)|>c$ for $|z|>R$.
As existence and location of a minimum are uncertain, start with $\mu=\inf_{z\in\Bbb C}|P(z)|$. This infimum could be zero and need not be a value of the function. Now apply the circle construction lemma with $c=\max(1,2\mu)$, which is possible even if $\mu=0$. Inside the disk $|z|\le R$ the continuous function $|P(z)|$ has a minimum, and this has to have the value $\mu$ at some point $z_*$, and this value has to be positive.
Now apply the open mapping theorem, the maximum principle or explore the polynomial expansion $P(z_*+v)$ in detail to find a contradiction to the existence of a positive minimum.
